# Using saxon & XPath 3.1 to parse JSON files

Tags: saxon

This is for the case of calling Saxon from a Java application. I understand that Saxon can use XPath 3.1 to run queries against JSON files. A couple of question on this:

1. Where is there an example of how to do this? I've done searches and find lots of answers on details of doing this, but noting on how to read in the file and perform queries. Is it the same as XML?
2. Is it possible to have a schema file for the JSON so returned values are correctly typed? If so, how?
3. Is XQuery also able to perform queries on JSON?
4. What version of Saxon supports this? (We are using 9.9.1.1 and want to know if I need to upgrade.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you don't run queries against JSON files; you run them against the data structure that results from parsing a JSON file, which is a structure of maps and arrays. You can parse the JSON file using the parse-json() or json-doc() functions, and then query the result using operators that work on maps and arrays. Some of these (and examples of their use) are shown in the spec at

https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-maps-and-arrays

Googling for "query maps arrays JSON XPath 3.1" finds quite a lot of useful material. Or get Priscilla Walmsley's book: http://www.datypic.com/books/xquery/chapter24.html

Data types: the data types of string, number, and boolean that are intrinsic to JSON are automatically recognized by their form. There's no capability to do further typing using a schema.

XQuery is a superset of XPath, but as far as JSON/Maps/Arrays are concerned, I think the facilities in XPath and those in XQuery are exactly the same.

Saxon has added a bit of extra conformance and performance in each successive release. 9.9 is pretty complete in its coverage; 10.0 adds some optimizations (like a new internal data structure for maps whose keys are all strings, such as you get when you parse JSON). Details of changes in successive Saxon releases are described in copious detail at http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!changes

Comment: Thank you and here's hoping you add schema support some day - in our case for datetime elements.

Comment: Hi; Follow-on question. Is there a way to query if the loaded data originated with XML or JSON. Or (probably better) if a schema file has been applied to the data? I'm asking because if it's JSON or no schema, then we can parse returned strings and if they match the format for the xml standard for datetime, convert them at a low level in our library.

Comment: I don't think I really understand the follow-up question. Probably best raised as a new question with an example.

Comment: I'm finally getting around to try and do this, and loading a JSON file the same way as an XML file throws a SaxonApiException. It clearly is expecting XML. Is there a link to the Java code to load a JSON file?

Comment: Supplementary questions (especially if there's a long gap since the origiinal) are best raised on a new thread.